# How to control excel chart source range through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to control and update the source (range) of an excel chart through VBA. The chart is ultimately going to be presented in a powerpoint presentation and the whole process shall update automatically.

I have tried using tables which doesn't give me the level of control I want. For example if i delete one datapoint the chart doesn't "shrink" accordingly.

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E5:E9"))
```

The current script doesn't run. But I just want to "set" a source range for a particular chart, preferably accessed by name. And if new datapoints are added I just run the script again and the new range will be the top cell in the column down to `.End(xlDown)`

Comment: If I remember correctly if you format the source range as table and create chart out of that and paste it in ppt it should auto update or atleast update on refresh.

Comment: `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E5:E9")` works for me

Comment: Also shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9703705/1140579)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I manged to  find a solution that works for me and made a function of it, if anyone else has the same problem. Nothing fancy but you can set a range like "A2:A14" and the chart will update with the new range. The function is called by sheet name, chart name and range like below:

```
Call changecharts("Sheet2", "Chart1", "A2:A11")

Public Function changecharts(sheeet As String,chartname As String, rnge As String)

Worksheets(sheeet).ChartObjects(chartname).Activate

With ActivateChart
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheeet).Range(rnge)
End With


End Function
```

Comment: Is that what is similar to what I commented below your post? :)